# Probability of an integer $a$ being larger than the greatest element in an random integer array $\left\langle a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...a_{n}\right\rangle$

Tags: probability, sorting

Say we have two integers $a_{1},a_{2}$ randomly chosen from the set of all integers . We can say that the probability of $P\left\{ a_{1}\geq a_{2}\right\} =\frac {1} {2}$ .

Similarly say we have an array of $n$ randomly chosen integers $\left\langle a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...a_{n}\right\rangle$  . Then we have another randomly chosen integer $a$ which is a key for comparison .

Then $P\left( a\geq a_{i}\right) =\frac {1} {2}\forall i\leq n$  then comparing our key element $a$ with all other elements in the array we can write $P\left( \left( a\geq a_{1}\right) \cap \left( a\geq a_{2}\right) \ldots \cap \left( a\geq a_{n}\right) \right) =\frac {1} {2^{n}} $

Then my question is that following similar logic , say we have sorted our array in non increasing order then can we write for some randomly chosen integer $a$ that $P\left( a\geq a_{1}\right) =\frac {1} {2^{n}}$ ? Where $a_{1}$ is the greatest element of the randomly selected array $\left\langle a_{1},a_{2},a_{3}...a_{n}\right\rangle$ .

Comment: Who you get $\frac{1}{2^n}$? They aren't independent. The probability will be $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: The integers in the array are randomly and independently selected

Comment: But when you are saying about the probability that $a$ is larger than all the integers, that is conditional probability. That is either greatest or not. Only two chances.

Comment: Wait we both are wrong , I got the correct answer. I’ll  post it in some time

Comment: Just a general writting tip. Do not use wording as "two integers randomly chosen" or things like that when you are not considering a uniform distribution, as you have seen, this induced me in not understanding your problem.

Comment: See my comment above. @nicola

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have $n+1$ integers ($a$ and the various $a_i$), so the probability that $a$ is the greatest is simply $\frac{1}{n+1}$.

Comment: Thx , I figured this out just now